# kABPersonAddressProperty causes crashes under ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am trying to be an ABRecordRef that represents the contact info of a person from addressbook. I built two functions that calls a function to fill in a personal data structure with the info in ABRecordRef.

Here comes the function declarations for the three functions:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) getAllContactProfiles{

    NSMutableArray *listOfProfile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //---get the contact information for the api
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeopleInAddressBook = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    //<- Here I loop through all the contacts and pass the ABRecordRef into the following function

    //---release the variables---
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(people);
    [listOfProfile autorelease];

    return listOfProfile;
}
```

**The Following Function**

```
+ (MSProfileEntry*) getPersonProfileThroughABRecordRef:(ABRecordRef) person{

    MSProfileEntry *mockProfile;
    ABRecordID recID=ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
    //get the user name
    CFStringRef firstName;
    firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);//it goes wrong here!
    CFStringRef lastName;
    lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    //bla bla bla.. the rest of the code
}
```

Everything goes very well. However, when I try to get the ABRecordRef through ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID like it is in the next method:

**The Next Method**

```
+ (MSProfileEntry*) getPersonProfileThroughContactId:(NSInteger*)contactId{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef person = 
    ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, (ABRecordID)contactId);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    if (person == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [MSContactUtil getPersonProfileThroughABRecordRef:person];
}
```

The whole app crashes on line:`ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`.

The problem now is that `ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);` works perfectly fine with `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` but causes the app to crash with `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID`.

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this problem? I really don't want to loop through entire contact base just to look for a contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a memory issue. I forgot to retain the "`addressBook`". By the time I executed the following line:

```
firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

The "`addressBook`" had been cleaned out already. Somehow we still need "`addressBook`" while querying for the detail information in "`person`".

So, remember to put in the following line, and you will be safe.

`CFRetain(addressBook)`;

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You pass `(NSInteger*)contactId` to `getPersonProfileThroughContactId` and after that you call `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, (ABRecordID)contactId);`. Actually you pass an address of the integer that holds the contact id and not the id itself...
- You check `if (person == nil)`, **BUT** person may not be nil - you should compare with `NULL`. I believe that it IS `NULL` in your case (because of my previous point).

These 2 things together cause the crash.

Just pass an integer as is - not its address...

**EDIT**:
Like this:

```
+ (MSProfileEntry*)getPersonProfileThroughContactId:(NSInteger)contactId
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. See the `getPersonProfileThroughContactId` method as it should be...